# I need to center 3 <div> on the webpage

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, text, center

I need to fix 3 `<div>`s in the center of my webpage. I tried to use `margin: 0 auto;` but it doesn't work, even using Bootstrap's grid. It's complicated because whatever I'll do the 3 `<div>`s don't fix exactly in the middle. It most to goes 3 buttons, and every button has a paragraph below.

```
<section class="contenedor">
        <nav>
            <ul><div class="contenedor">
                <li class="col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/icono-1.png" alt="responsive" class="center-block"></a>
                    <p class="boton-textT"> 
                                            RESPONSIVE</p>
                    <p class="boton-textT">WEB DESIGN</p>

                    <p class="boton-text col-md-12 ">
                    We create scalable Internet services.
                    The architecture of the content and 
                    presentation is adapted to the screen
                    size and device type. We create 
                    Responsive Web Design.
                    </p></li>


                <li class="boton2 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/icono-2.png" alt="mobile" class="center-block"></a>
                    <p class="boton-textT"> 
                                            MOBILE</p>
                    <p class="boton-textT">APPLICATIONS
                    </p>
                    <p class="boton-text col-md-12">
                    We design the user interfaces 
                    of mobile applications. We know the 
                    iPhone users' needs as well as Metro 
                    system's requirements. Developers 
                    respect quality and organization 
                    of our work, clients love it.
                    </p></li>

                <li class="boton3 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="imagenes/icono-3.png" alt="web" class="center-block"></a>
                    <p class="boton-textT"> 
                    WEB</p>
                    <p class="boton-textT">APPLICATIONS
                    </p>
                    <p class="boton-text col-md-12">
                    We are building UI for web 
                    applications. We understand both: 
                    the strength of trends 
                    and technology constraints. At the 
                    end of the day the user is still the 
                    most important.
                    </p></li>
                    </div>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </section>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want three elements centered on your page with equal width. So set the width of each one to 33% and set to inline-block

Comment: Thanks!! I already resolved, removing <ul><div class="contenedor"> and other errors.  Then I put <ul id="nav-container"> "                                                       CSS: #nav-container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}" and It is perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

Grids are based on 12:

```
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
<div class="col-md-4"></div>
```

As pointed out, the code needs to be cleaned up and validated.

Comment: That was I did!! Thanks!! I already resolved, removing <ul><div class="contenedor"> and other errors.  Then I put <ul id="nav-container"> "                                                       CSS: #nav-container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}" and It is perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

**1. Your mark up is wrong**

You wrapped the `li`s with `div.contenedor` this is not a standard practice. Please remove it.

**2. Need a better understand bootstrap's grid system.**

It's divided into `12` basically. If you want to put 3 items on a row and want them to be well-aligned horizontally, you need to use `col-**-4`, not `-3` there.

Reading this http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid  will help you understand it better.

---

I editted some of your code here - http://jsfiddle.net/fktkeu9r/

Comment: So true!! Thanks!! I already resolved, removing <ul><div class="contenedor"> and other errors.  Then I put <ul id="nav-container"> "                                                       CSS: #nav-container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}" and It is perfect!!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to edit your CSS to something like:

```
.contenedor 
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! I already resolved, removing <ul><div class="contenedor"> and other errors.  Then I put <ul id="nav-container"> "                                                       CSS: #nav-container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding-bottom: 50px;
}" and It is perfect!!